# Placing a div below two other div elements of different size

Tags: html, css

Would like to place the bottom (green) container below the left and right containers (red and blue) but still keep it inside the main (black) container. Cannot get it to work. Any suggestions? ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tWTsj/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<div class="main_container">

    <div class="left_container">
    </div>

    <div class="right_container">
    </div>

    <div class="bottom_container">
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
div.main_container {
    background: #000;
    border: none;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

div.left_container {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    width: 220px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

div.right_container {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 220px;
    width: 715px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

div.bottom_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

​

Comment: Your left container is set to min-height:100% so how can you expect to place something under it?

Comment: I need the left container to fill the remainder of the height, which is what I need to work around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should size the height of the left container to be everything except `100px` and put the green container on the bottom of the whole thing.

```
div.bottom_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
div.left_container {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    top: 0;
    width: 220px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I need the left container to have a fluid height, at the moment if I place more content inside the left container it is clipped: http://jsfiddle.net/tWTsj/3/ Any ideas?

Comment: You might actually want something like this, using `float:left;` and `clear:both;`: http://jsfiddle.net/tWTsj/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
```

add these two properties in div.bottom_container . hope you are getting what you expect

Comment: That would cause the bottom container to fall out of the main container.